# Why does symfony remove autoincrement in migrations?

Tags: php, symfony, migration

Available:

- Symfony 5.4
- PostgreSQL 13

Created an entity where the **id** field is an auto-increment

```php
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
* @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", options={"autoincrement":true})
*/
private integer $id;
```

Then I executed the **doctrine:migrations:diff** command, a php file with migrations was created (at this moment id is auto-increment). Next, I executed the **doctrine:migrations:migrate** command, a table was created in the database (at this moment, too, id is auto-increment). Next, I add a new field to the entity, create a new migration with the **doctrine:migrations:diff** command, create a migration in which symfony removes the auto-increment from id.

Comment: Please show the content of both migrations

Comment: Which version of doctrine / dbal are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to replicate your issue.
I've seen Doctrine doing odd things with the 'options' attribute before, e.g. being completely ignored. However, this is odd that it's seeing it at first, creating the migration and then removing it with a second migration.

If your issue is with auto-increment, you could try changing to the following:

```php
#[ORM\Id]
#[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'IDENTITY')]
#[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
private $id;
```

This seems to do the trick for me.
I am using attributes, but you can adapt them to annotations.

Make sure you DROP any previously created sequences, otherwise you will have more issues with migrations, e.g. manually running `DROP SEQUENCE your_table_name_id_seq CASCADE`